# Como separar uma string em pedaços?

Tags: c, c++, string

Em outras linguagens existe o `split`, `explode` ou algo parecido que picota a *string* em pedaços de acordo com algum separador. Existe algo pronto em C ou tenho que fazer na mão?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não tem algo tão pronto, mas existe o [`strtok()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) que analisa a *string* e substitui um delimitador especificado por um caractere nulo e assim o que era uma única *string* vai virando várias, já que o nulo termina a *string* naquele ponto.

Mas note que ele não devolve um *array* de *strings*  como é comum em outras linguagens, tão pouco faz com todos delimitadores. Ele faz apenas com o primeiro que encontrar, para fazer no segundo precisa roda o `strtok()` novamente e assim por diante. É claro que todo programador C faz alguma(s) função(ões) utilitárias para facilitar e entregar o que deseja.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char frutas[] = "banana,laranja,morango";
    int tamanho = strlen(frutas); //isto funciona só para delimitador de 1 caractere
    char *token = strtok(frutas, ",");
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) printf(token[i] == 0 ? "\\0" : "%c", token[i]);
    while(token != NULL) {
        printf("\n%s", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SmIr3c). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qlteofwr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Tokenize.c).

Answer (score 1):

Em C++ não existe uma função nativa 'split' para strings.

Pesquisando o assunto encontra-se uma enorme variedade de maneiras de se separar uma string.

Alguns exemplos que achei interessante.

---

#### Exemplo 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   // string a ser separada
   string tokenString { "aaa     bbb ccc" };

   // as sub-strings separadas vão ser colocadas neste vetor
   vector<string> tokens;

   // stream de strings de input inicializado com a string a ser separada
   istringstream tokenizer { tokenString };

   // variável de trabalho
   string token;

   // separa as string por espaço e coloca no vetor destino
   while (tokenizer >> token)
     tokens.push_back(token);

   // mostra na tela as sub-strings separadas
   for (const string& token: tokens)
       cout << "* [" << token << "]\n";
}
```

Resultado do exemplo 1:

```
* [aaa]
* [bbb]
* [ccc]
```

---

#### Exemplo 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   // string a ser separada
   string tokenString { "aaa, bbb, ccc,,ddd   ,   eee" };

   // as sub-strings separadas vão ser colocadas neste vetor
   vector<string> tokens;

   // stream de strings de input inicializado com a string a ser separada
   istringstream tokenizer { tokenString };

   // variável de trabalho
   string token;

   // separa as sub-strings por vírgula e coloca no vetor destino
   while (getline(tokenizer, token, ','))
      tokens.push_back(token);

   // mostra na tela as sub-strings separadas
   for (const string& token: tokens)
       cout << "* [" << token << "]\n";
}
```

Resultado do exemplo 2:

```
* [aaa]
* [ bbb]
* [ ccc]
* []
* [ddd   ]
* [   eee]
```

Notar que foram mantidos os espaços nas sub-strings destino. (Seria o caso de usar uma outra função comum para strings chamada 'trim' que *também* não existe em C++).

---

#### Exemplo 3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   // string a ser separada
   string tokenString { "aaa, bbb, ccc,,ddd   ,   eee" };

   // as sub-strings separadas vão ser colocadas neste vetor
   vector<string> tokens;

   // expressão regular contendo os delimitadores: espaço e vírgula
   regex delimiters { "[\\s,]+" };

   // cria um iterator para um objeto contendo as sub-strings separadas
   // obs. estou usando uma "receita" pronta, não sei o motivo exato do parametro '-1'
   sregex_token_iterator tokens_begin { tokenString.begin(), tokenString.end(), delimiters, -1 };

   // iterator finalizador
   auto tokens_end = sregex_token_iterator {};

   // copia as sub-strings separadas para o vetor destino
   for (auto token_it = tokens_begin; token_it != tokens_end; token_it++)
      tokens.push_back(*token_it);

   // mostra na tela as sub-strings separadas
   for (const string& token: tokens)
       cout << "* [" << token << "]\n";
}
```

Resultado do exemplo 3:

```
* [aaa]
* [bbb]
* [ccc]
* [ddd]
* [eee]
```

---

That's all for now folks.