# Separar uma string em 2 de um arquivo

Tags: c, arquivo

Eu estou com dificuldade em separa uma string consultada de um arquivo em duas.

o arquivo está assim alex 6461 anddre 979794 douglas 6469794 gustavo ...

eu quero pegar o caracteres pego na linha e dividir em 2 strings assim nome: alex tel:6461.

Quem puder me ajudar eu agreço muito.

```
void Buscar_Registro()
{
FILE *fp;
Agenda A;
Agenda *list;
list=&A;
int linha,i=0;
char c,nome[1001],nome2[1001];
char *ch;


 fp = fopen("AgendaDeContatos.txt","r+");
 if(fp == NULL)
    {
    printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo.\n");
    return(0);
    }
  printf("\nDigite a posição do registro:\n");
  scanf("%d",&linha);

    while(i<1001 - 1 &&(c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if(linha==1 && c!='\n'){
//      printf("%c",c);
         nome[i++]= c;
         nome[i]='\0';
         nome2[1001]="";
         strcpy(nome2,nome);


    }
    if(c=='\n'){
        linha--;

    }
    }


    fclose (fp);

}
```

Código Completo:
https://pastebin.com/edit/Fhws9vsE

Comment: Qual a informação do arquivo ? De que forma é para separar ? Qual o código que é suposto fazer isso ?

Comment: o código pecorre uma certa quantidade de linhas selecionado 
até a quebra de linha e armazena os caracteres na variavel "c"

Comment: arquivo 

alex 6461 
anddre 979794 
douglas 6469794 
gustavo 3131346 
leadnro 679764 
matrix 9777946 
oscar 97946 
vinicius 649413 
zion 646461

Comment: eu quero pegar o caracteres pego na linha e dividir em 2 strings assim nome: alex  tel:6461

Comment: Todas essas informações são relevantes à pergunta e ajudam a quem quer responder. Por esse motivo deve editar a pergunta colocando essas informações nela.

Comment: ja editei, eu acho que agora está certo

Comment: eu consegui transformar os caracteres lido da linha em string mas o resto ta dificil =(

Comment: Você pode usar  a função `strchr` da biblioteca `string.h` ([veja aqui](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strchr.htm)) para obter a posição de um caracter ' '(espaço). E depois faz o mesmo para obter o segundo espaço. Assim, você pega os caracteres da string da posição 1 até a posição 2. 

Irá precisar ainda alocar memória com [`malloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) ou [`calloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm) para criar uma nova string com os caracteres.

Comment: Possível duplicado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190755/como-separar-uma-string-em-peda%C3%A7os?rq=1

Comment: eu até entendi mas me da um exemplo ai por favor

Comment: const char ch2 = ' ';
 char * ret = strchr(nome2, ch2);
seria isso  ?

Comment: pode deixar finalmente eu consegui kkkkkkkkk